# Where are C/C++ Preprocessor settings in project properties UI in VS 2015 Community Edition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, preprocessor-directive, vs-community-edition

With the hope of getting trained for C++ as a zero newbie, I was following directives to create a C++ dev environment on a PC equipped with Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

I create a new C++ project on VS 2015 CE
[image: empty C++ Project in VS CE]

When I right-click project properties, I cannot locate C/C++ > Preprocessor - it's just not there as can be seen from the screenshot.

[image]

So trying to figure out how on Earth I can add some custom preprocessor definitions here. :-(

Comment: I could not figure out why this is the case, but i can reproduce this behavior. If you simply select another project type than "Empty Project" (e.g. "Win32 Project" or "Win 32 Console Application") the property page will show up as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add at least one `.cpp` or `.c` file to your project (or, more generally, an item with *ItemType* "*C/C++ Compiler*").

A desired entry will appear in *Project Property Pages* (exactly where you expect it to be):

> *Configuration properties* -> *C/C++*

There will be subentry "*Preprocessor*".

Alternatively, you may create a project of type

> *Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32 Console Application* (or, more general,  *Win32 Project*)

This type of projects already contains C++ files with some simple code.